# Unity 3d scenes comes "gold"

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, scene, scene-manager

Im new in Unity. Im watched several tutorials and I cant manage this:

When I reloaded an Scene, the new scene comes "gold". See the images:

[image]

[image]

Here the code I use:

`public void reloadGame(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }`

Could somebody help me ? Thank in advanced!

Comment: Are you referring to the objects' color? This is likely due to the lightning in the scene. Run the scene and look at the `Directional Light` Object in your scene. It has an `Intensity` which might give you a result like this. Find out why it is changed when you load the scene. Codewise it has nothing to do with how you loaded the scene, but rather the functionality of the game.

Comment: It looks like ambient light is gone. Check the settings in your lighting window.